# Adding sprite to CCParallaxNode while character moves?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Using the `[CCParallaxNode node]` class in `cocos2d`, I know how to add sprites to the parallax. But I was adding them BEFORE the character started moving with offset set to `0`:

```
[parallaxBack addChild:ground1 z:1 parallaxRatio:CloseElementsSpeed positionOffset:L4];
 [parallaxBack addChild:ground2 z:1 parallaxRatio:CloseElementsSpeed positionOffset:L5];
```

Now, I am trying to add a new sprite after the character has already started to move. I probably don't add the character to the right position.
How can I add a new sprite with an offset to the current position of the parallax? (I have tried to subtract its current position - it didn't work.)

```
//new sprite after a while - I can't see the character.
[parallaxBack addChild:man z:1 parallaxRatio:CloseElementsSpeed positionOffset:L4];
```